# Equivalent of adding to a denominator?

Tags: inequality, fractions

Given the inequality $\frac{n}{m} \ge \frac{1}{2}$, I want to add $1$ to both $n$ and $m$:
$$\frac{n+1}{m+1}.$$

What would be the equivalent operation on the RHS of the equation?

Adding $1$ to $n$ is equivalent to $+\frac{1}{m}$ on both sides, but what about adding $1$ to $m$?

Answer (score 6):

I think this should do it:

$$\begin{align}\frac nm&\ge a\\
n&\ge am+a-a\\
n&\ge a(m+1)-a\\
\frac n{m+1}&\ge a-\frac a{m+1}\\
\frac{n+1}{m+1}&\ge a+\frac{1-a}{m+1}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint 1**
$$\frac{n}{m}=\frac{n+1}{m+1}+\left(\frac{n}{m}-\frac{n+1}{m+1}\right)$$
and
$$ a \leq b+c \iff a-b \leq c $$
**Hint 2**
$$\frac{n}{m}=\frac{n+1}{m+1}\cdot\left(\frac{n}{m}\cdot\frac{m+1}{n+1}\right)$$
and,
$$ a \leq b\cdot c \iff \frac{a}{b} \leq c \qquad \text{ if }\ b>0 \\ a \leq b\cdot c \iff \frac{a}{b} \geq c \qquad \text{ if }\ b<0 $$

Comment: Note that you can "generalize" these techniques in order to go from $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ to $\frac{\gamma}{\nu}$ for any $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\nu \in \Bbb R$ with $\beta,\nu\neq 0$.

Comment: Doesn't the last statement only hold if $b$ is positive? Isn't this a counter-example: $a=5,b=-1,c=-6$? Then the last statement claims $5\leq6 \iff -5 \leq -6$. Or did I do something dumb?

Comment: @jpmc26 You are right! thanks, I edited the answer